# Expo: console.log stopped showing up

Tags: react-native, terminal, expo, console.log

1. SDK Version: 45
2. Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): iOS
3. Add the appropriate "Tag" based on what Expo library you have a question on.

My managed expo project suddenly stopped showing console.log on terminal when I run `expo run:ios`.
Also, auto bundling on file changes also stopped.

The following is the version information I get when I run `npm list`.

```
├── @babel/core@7.18.10
├── @primer/primitives@7.9.0
├── @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.17.9
├── @react-native-firebase/analytics@15.3.0
├── @react-native-firebase/app@15.3.0
├── @react-native-firebase/auth@15.3.0
├── @react-native-firebase/firestore@15.3.0
├── @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.3.2
├── @react-navigation/native-stack@6.7.0
├── @react-navigation/native@6.0.11
├── @sanity/client@3.3.3
├── @shopify/restyle@2.1.0
├── @types/flat@5.0.2
├── @types/lodash@4.14.184
├── @types/react-native@0.66.21
├── @types/react@17.0.48
├── dotenv@16.0.1
├── expo-apple-authentication@4.2.1
├── expo-av@11.2.3
├── expo-build-properties@0.2.0
├── expo-dev-client@1.0.1
├── expo-splash-screen@0.15.1
├── expo-status-bar@1.3.0
├── expo@45.0.8
├── flat@5.0.2
├── lodash@4.17.21
├── react-dom@17.0.2
├── react-native-pager-view@5.4.15
├── react-native-reanimated@2.8.0
├── react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4
├── react-native-screens@3.11.1
├── react-native-web@0.17.7
├── react-native@0.68.2
├── react@17.0.2
└── typescript@4.3.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by upgrading expo sdk from `45` to `46` by executing `expo-cli upgrade`.

To find more information about expo sdk migration: please refer to "Upgrading your app" section of [this post](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-46-c2a1655f63f7).

Answer (score 0):

For me, removing @types/react-native did the trick.